# Is there a digital to analog converter module in network cards?

Tags: communication, ethernet, digital-communications

Network cards convert digital bit streams to an analog signal for transmission. Do they have a DAC module? If so, how fast is it?

Comment: Yes, it's part of the PHY chip. Fast enough.

Comment: I'm not super well versed in phys but I'm pretty sure you don't have access to the DACS in a phy. The DA

Comment: Probably depends on the network type and on whether a 1-bit DAC really qualifies for a DAC (for network types which only send 1 bit per symbol).

Comment: @jcaron, yes it counts. Besides that, are there higher bit DAC in the communication network? For example, if I want to transmit in the QAM fashion through a fiber optic ethernet cable.

Answer (score 4):

> Do they have a DAC module?

Yes. It usually is an integral part of transmit path in the PHY, or an integrated PHY-MAC chip, sometimes embedded in the SoC/MCU. So, the "module" is there, but you can't easily access it directly.

> If so, how fast is it?

For Fast Ethernet (100BASE-TX), the DAC is operating at 125Ms/s. The transmit clock is derived from the PHY's transmit data stream clock, and that's derived from the [R]MII TX clock used to push data from the MAC to the PHY. The ADC is operating at 125Ms/s as well. Its clock is recovered from the incoming data stream - a PLL locks the clock onto the incoming signal, and this clock drives the ADC. A FIFO sits between the receive circuitry and the [R]MII interface, so that the RX clock on the MAC interface is decoupled from the TX clock at the other end of the wire. Time-synchronous ethernet, used in special applications, complicates this a bit.

Gigabit Ethernet PHYs for 1000BASE-TX use the data pairs in a bidirectional fashion, via a hybrid, and have a DAC and an ADC connected to the TX/RX ports of the hybrid, respectively. There's a lot of DSP needed to neutralize the near-end echo and crosstalk, as well as to equalize the cable losses. Some of the signal processing can be disabled/bypassed.

The ADC and the DAC are internal implementation details and are not directly accessible other than in chip test mode. Chip test modes are proprietary, unfortunately, so it wouldn't be easy to repurpose an Ethernet PHY as a low-resolution general-purpose ADC/DAC that way.

> What's the resolution? (a question you didn't ask)

It's low for a 100BASE-TX PHY.

The DAC in the transmit path is 1.6 bits - it has three output levels.

A 6-bit ADC with closed-loop gain control would be typical for the receive path. Some implementations use an 8-bit ADC with fixed gain.

> How much power do they consume? High-speed DAC usually has large working power.

How large is "large"?

Old 100BASE-TX PHYs - say LAN83C185 - consume about 0.4W at any utilization of TX and RX channels. That's the limiting case for a **full PHY**. The DAC consumes a small part of it, I'd guess < 10%. Power-saving modes exist in newer parts.

More modern parts can cut this down a bit. Some of the power that the chip consumes is dissipated **outside** of the chip - in the magnetics, cable and termination resistors.